# Alternatives for the suffix '-rooted'

Tags: word-request, suffixes

I'm looking for an alternative suffix to **'-rooted'**. The word combination will be with 'spiritually-...'.

I'm thinking of using **'spiritually-rooted practice'** but **'rooted'** sounds so 'just-dropped'. On the other hand, the meaning it conveys is spot on.

But not the following:

The spiritually-assisted practice
The spiritually-based practice
The spiritually-enabled practice
The spiritually-supported practice
The spiritually-endorsed practice
The spiritually-encouraged practice

Maybe somebody has something.

Comment: Hyphenation is not normally used after an *-ly* word in compound adjectives. Stylistically, it's much more common to leave all of your examples without a hyphen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what part of the meaning of 'spiritually-rooted' you're  trying to capture you could go a couple of different ways with this.

'Spiritually-grounded' gives it the same sense of being connected with the earth as 'spiritually-rooted' does.

'Spiritually-originated' gives it the sense that it starts from spirit in the same way a plant starts from its roots. You could also say 'spiritually-inspired', which is similar.

'Spiritually-anchored' says that it is held in place by spirit like a plant is held in place by its roots.